# Door handle starting to come out

Tags: repair, door, trim, door-handle

The lock and handle assembly in my door (exterior) is starting to come out.

[image: My door handle]

(This photo is taken looking down at the door -- the assembly is parallel to the ground. The black gasket seems to be rubber, and it is the only thing between the metal of the car and the metal of the handle assembly.)

What type of adhesive (or is there a bolt missing?) should I use to repair this?

My car is a 1993 Mazda Miata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the handle are two studs with nuts that hold the handle in place.

[image]

You will need to take the interior door panel off and reach into the door to tighten these nuts.

Comment: i am honestly relieved that it's not glue. thank you!

Comment: maybe a dab of locktite blue to hold them tight.